# Anyone seen a native Android push notification example

Tags: android, mobilepush-android

now that push notification is on general release, is there a sample native android app that demonstrates it?

I thought I had the code right when an entry appeared i the "Mobile Push Registrations" page, but when I used the test page to send a JSON string to my app, and set a breakpoint in the interface function, the code never got to the function.

Then I refreshed the "Mobile Push Registrations" page and the entry had disappeared.

My OnCreate code is pretty much a copy and paste from the documentation:

```
static public ReceivePushNotification rp = new ReceivePushNotification ();;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new KeyImpl(), MainActivity.class);
  SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().setPushNotificationReceiver(rp);
}
```

and then in the ReceivePushNotification.java file:

```
public class ReceivePushNotification extends Activity implements PushNotificationInterface {

    @Override
    public void onPushMessageReceived(Bundle message) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Pushed");
        AlertDialog chooseFault = builder.create();
        chooseFault.show();
    }

}
```

But it never gets into OnPushMessageReceived!

Comment: Your actual issue seems to be specifically the Android portion and so might receive better answers elsewhere.

Comment: Did you see any errors when you used the test page to send a push notification?